# create a virtual machine from the CLI? (KVM)

Tags: command-line, system-installation, virtual-machine, kvm, webserver

How can I create a virtual machine [from the CLI](https://www.rivy.org/2013/02/creating-a-kvm-virtual-machine/)?

> Creating a Virtual Machine
>
> ```
> First, download an ISO cd image of some OS you want to run. For Ubuntu, you can find these at:
>
>     http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/download 
>
> Double click on the name of the host. The Status column should read Active
>
> Right click on the name of the host, and select New
> This will start a wizard to guide you through the rest of your VM creation
>     Enter your virtual machine details
>
>         Name: foo
>
>         Choose Local install media (ISO image or CDROM), or you can use another method if you know what you're doing
>
>         Forward 
>     Locate your install media
>
>         Use ISO image
>
>         Browse to find the ISO you downloaded earlier
>
>         Optional: Select the matching OS Type
>
>         Optional: Select the matching Version
>
>         Forward
> ```

Primarily just for my own edification.

Comment: Just use `virsh`? What problem do you have with it?

Comment: @EgorVasilyev well, creating a config file from scratch on the CLI based on an ISO...have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use:

```
virt-install \
--name vm_name \
--ram=2048 \
--vcpus=2 \
--disk pool=guest_images,size=30,bus=virtio,format=qcow2 \
--cdrom /var/iso/debian.iso \
--network bridge=kvmbr0,model=virtio \
--graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0,password=Qwerty1234 \
--boot cdrom,hd,menu=on
```

Where `/var/iso/debian.iso` - path to iso image

`guest_images` - disk pool, you need to create it before vm

Comment: and how do you run the "install" for the above debian?

Comment: @Thufir, what do you mean? Installation will start automatically because i use boot order with cdrom first. And after this i can connect via VNC to manage installation process

Comment: Too bad I can't figure out how to get `virt-install` onto my Ubuntu machine!

Answer (score 1):

I often use qemu-kvm the old way with this kind of qemu command :

`qemu-img create mydisk.img 10G`

`qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d -cdrom image.iso -m 512 -hda mydisk.img`

virsh will launch qemu-kvm. But it need some config file.
Sometime it's easier to bypass all this xml lines and just launch the vm.

Answer (score 0):

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ virsh connect qemu:///system

thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ virsh list
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 1     asteriskNOW                    running

thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ virsh dumpxml AsteriskNow > guest.xml
error: failed to get domain 'AsteriskNow'
error: Domain not found: no domain with matching name 'AsteriskNow'
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ virsh dumpxml 1 > guest.xml
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ cat guest.xml 
<domain type='kvm' id='1'>
  <name>asteriskNOW</name>
  <uuid>e57fb835-cdfa-4234-b0c2-72b17178646a</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>997376</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>997376</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-artful'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <vmport state='off'/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='full'>
    <model fallback='forbid'>Nehalem</model>
    <feature policy='require' name='vme'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='x2apic'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='hypervisor'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/thufir/Downloads/AsteriskNow-1013-current-64.iso'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <alias name='ide0-0-0'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'>
      <alias name='pci.0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <alias name='ide'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <alias name='virtio-serial0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:99:ac:da'/>
      <source network='default' bridge='virbr0'/>
      <target dev='vnet0'/>
      <model type='rtl8139'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/2'/>
      <target port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/2'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/2'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='spicevmc'>
      <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0' state='disconnected'/>
      <alias name='channel0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input0'/>
    </input>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input1'/>
    </input>
    <graphics type='spice' port='5900' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1'>
      <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
      <image compression='off'/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <alias name='sound0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' vgamem='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <alias name='redir0'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <alias name='redir1'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='apparmor' relabel='yes'>
    <label>libvirt-e57fb835-cdfa-4234-b0c2-72b17178646a</label>
    <imagelabel>libvirt-e57fb835-cdfa-4234-b0c2-72b17178646a</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='dac' relabel='yes'>
    <label>+64055:+130</label>
    <imagelabel>+64055:+130</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
</domain>

thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$
```

and then

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ virsh list
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------

thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ virsh create guest.xml 
Domain asteriskNOW created from guest.xml

thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ virsh list
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 2     asteriskNOW                    running

thufir@dur:~$
```

although I cheated by using `virt-manager` to create the initial `guest`...